# Trouble linking commands together

Tags: powershell, file

So i'm pretty new to powershell and I'm trying to list all contents of a directory(on my vm) while stating if each is a reg file or directory along with it's path/size.
the code I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd c:\
foreach ($item in get-childitem -Path c:\) {
    Write-Host $item
}
########
if(Test-Path $item){
    Write-Host "Regular File" $item
}
else {
    Write-Host "Directory" $item
}
```

I can get all of the contents to print, but when I try to state whether file/directory, only one `.txt` file says "Regular File" next to it. I've been at it for hours on end and get figure it out. Also, my output doesn't state "directory" next to directories...

Comment: Why are you adding a bash shebang for a PowerShell script?

Comment: Your if () {...} else {...} code needs to be moved into the foreach block { ... between braces ... } and `Test-Path` will be successful for both regular files and directories so it will always say "Regular File".  Please read up on the about pages and come back after if you still have questions.  [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2)  [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#examples)

Comment: [about_if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.2)  [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Use [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.2) and [Get-Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-7.2) while you are learning.  Rarely use `Write-Host` unless you absolutely need to write some text to the screen and even then think twice.  Read [about_Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.2) and all the linked pages under See Also section

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can enumerate the files and folders on your `C` Drive one level deep with their current size (if it's a folder, look for the files inside and get a sum of it's Length). Regarding trying to *"state whether file / directory"*, you don't need to apply any logic to it, [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) and [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) have an [`Attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-6.0) property which gives you this information already.

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ | & {
    process {
        $object = [ordered]@{
            Attributes = $_.Attributes
            Path       = $_.Name # change to $_.FullName for the Path
            Length     = $_.Length / 1mb
        }

        if($_ -is [IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
            foreach($file in $_.EnumerateFiles()) {
                $object['Length'] += $file.Length / 1mb
            }
        }
        $object['Length'] = [math]::Round($object['Length'], 2).ToString() + ' Mb'
        [pscustomobject] $object
    }
}
```

If you want something more complex, i.e. seeing the hierarchy of a directory, like [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command)#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20tree%20is%20a,%2C%20Microsoft%20Windows%2C%20and%20ReactOS.) does, with  the corresponding sizes you can check out [this module](https://github.com/santysq/PSTree).